# How to extract Unix-style local filepaths from a string?

Tags: java, regex, filepath

Let's say I have a string which contains a Unix-style local path to a file like in following examples:

```
 String s1 = "something something ./files/icon.gif";
 String s2 = "The files are texts/text1.txt and texts/text2.txt";
 String s3 = "<img src="images/img/run.png" alt="" />"
```

So, I'd need to extract only filepaths:

```
 "./files/icon.gif"
 "texts/text1.txt", "texts/text2.txt"
 "images/img/run.png"
```

I've come up with the following regex:

```
\.?[[a-zA-Z0-9]*/]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

And it does the job for these test cases.

Now, my worries are that this *could* pull out other text which is not a filepath and only looks like one because it has slashes and dots in the right places.

Is there a better way to handle this problem (possibly even without using regular expressions)?

Comment: I don't see how you could write something capable of discriminating between an actual file path and something that just *looks* like a file path. Not unless you are also able to validate those paths as actual paths to existing files. What if someone writes "On Stackoverflow you can vote answers up/down". "up/down" can be a file path, and there's no way of knowing without some kind of context awareness or artifical intelligence.

Comment: @johusman: Exactly. My current regex wouldn't extract "up/down", but only because it doesn't have a file extension. Since, a file indeed doesn't have to have an extension, this isn't a good reason.

Comment: the very term "extension" is specific to DOS/Windows where it is indeed a special part of a file name. On Unix-like systems it's just a part of a file name that happen to be separated by dot from the rest of it. So you're completely right here, it's not going to help.

Comment: Is there no standard Java class that does this, something corresponding to Perl’s [File::Basename::fileparse()](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)? Using regexes on one’s own for this seems a poor idea, particularly Java’s given how Unicode‐pesky they are.

Comment: @tchrist, Java has it's own class for working with file paths, but it's not the problem here. The problem is to figure out where are the paths, and nothing like fileparse() is going to help you here. As johusman have pointed out, some sort of Sci-Fi AI is needed for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. Unix file names can contain literally anything except for NULs and `/`s, so any string with no embedded NULs is a valid path. See:

```
[alqualos@brededor tmp]$ mkdir -p 'String s1 = "something something ./files/icon.gif";'
[alqualos@brededor tmp]$ ll -d String*
drwxr-xr-x 3 alqualos alqualos   4096 2011-02-26 16:31 String s1 = "something something .
[alqualos@brededor tmp]$ ll String\ s1\ \=\ \"something\ something\ ./
total 4K
drwxr-xr-x 3 alqualos alqualos 4096 2011-02-26 16:31 files
[alqualos@brededor tmp]$ ll String\ s1\ \=\ \"something\ something\ ./files/
total 4K
drwxr-xr-x 2 alqualos alqualos 4096 2011-02-26 16:31 icon.gif";
```

So all your strings are valid file paths. If you want to extract everything that looks like "reasonable" paths, then you must define "reasonable" first and even then you'll probably fail because of something like "TCP/IP" in the source text.

Comment: It seems that really the only way to go here is to define "reasonable" file names that cover a large enough subset of cases, as you suggested. Thanks!